# Proguard return an error when I try to use it in Eclipse

Tags: android, sdk, proguard

I am trying to export an Android application using ProGuard but when I do it I receive this error of the console:

```
[2014-04-18 16:04:37 - YesMa] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-04-18 16:04:37 - YesMa] java.io.FileNotFoundException: Android\YesMa\proguard\dump.txt (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
[2014-04-18 16:04:37 - YesMa]   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
[2014-04-18 16:04:37 - YesMa]   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
[2014-04-18 16:04:37 - YesMa]   at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[2014-04-18 16:04:37 - YesMa]   at proguard.FileWordReader.<init>(FileWordReader.java:39)
[2014-04-18 16:04:37 - YesMa]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseIncludeArgument(ConfigurationParser.java:217)
[2014-04-18 16:04:37 - YesMa]   at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:124)
[2014-04-18 16:04:37 - YesMa]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

In my project I have:

**project.properties**

```
# Many comments
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
android.library.reference.2=../gridlayout_v7
```

**proguard-project.txt**

```
# Many comments
```

Here "SDK-PATH...\tools\proguard\bin\" I have written this in the three files:

```
SET PROGUARD_HOME="C:\Users\Alberto\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\proguard"

java -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*
```

I don't understand the error, I have seen many post but I haven't found the solution. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem putting the names of all folders of my workspace path without spaces. For example: "A - X" --> "A-X"